# Exporting WebCenter Content to XML

Tags: webcenter, oracle-ucm

I am attempting to migrate content from an Oracle's WebCenter CMS into our organizations primary CMS. All the different parts of the page templates are separate xml snippets that get pull together and converted into html for production deployments. I am trying to find a way to export the page into xml to just get at the content. I don't need styles or js or images.

There are some built in web services and an ability to create custom ones. Is there any way to get the system to output xml or get the xml to give me a mapping of all the files so I can merge them myself?

Comment: Is this for a Site Studio website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this will do what you want, but if you add &IsSoap=1 to the end of the URL then the request is returned in XML format. You can view the page data by using the following settings:
• IsJava
• IsSoap
• IsJson
• IsPageDebug
These may help as well. [Here](https://blogs.oracle.com/kyle/entry/page_debugging_easier_in_ucm_11g) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/doc.1111/e10726/c08_config_ref.htm#CSIDO674).

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If this is for a Site Studio website, you should be able to turn on sitestudio section tracing, clear the server ouput, view the website page, refresh the output and it should show you details about the content items it retrieved.